# What's answer of this question?

Tags: sentence

> **Question:** When I was two, my Brother was half my age. I'm a hundred
>   now. Can you tell me how old is my Brother ?

My answer was a number but everyone keep saying the answer is **Yes** or **No**.

In this sentence **Can you tell me how old is my Brother**. What am i miss understanding here ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to have nothing to do with the English language.

Comment: The question is not grammatical.

Comment: Some logicians might ask this question (with corrected grammar) even though their brother had died. Logicians sometimes don't realise that pragmatics usually trumps what they see as precisionist language, in the real world.

Comment: This is a very common joke in English, 7urkm3n.  Kyle has explained it below.

Comment: This should have been migrated to ELL to help the OP. It's a great question for there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Can you tell me how old is my Brother?" Yes, you **can** tell him how old he is. You're assuming that this is asking "How old is my brother?", though in the most literal reading, it is merely asking **if** you can answer. In common language these questions are equivalent, save the occasional dad-joke.

Answer (score -1):

Your Brother Would Be 99 years old because when you are 2 and your brother
 was half your age that means he was one year younger than you your entire life.

Comment: You missed the riddle. It's not really asking for an answer.